# a configure port for win32

Tags: makefile, mingw, configure, msys

I'm on windows, where do I get the configure tool, that is used in make files?
I installed msys and mingw, as I thought it would be included.

any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no configure tool as such. `configure` is a shell script. It is not "used in make files", but is provided with packages to create makefiles for different environments and/or with user-definable options set as wanted.

If you want to build a package that you have downloaded, you can use MSYS' bash shell to run the included `configure` script. If you want to create a configure script for a package of your own, you should look at GNU's autotools.

Comment: Good explanation, but I've seen quite a few Makefiles that invoke configure.

Answer (score 0):

Try [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) - gives you a complete UNIX environment on Windows.